# module installation - Mock

Tags: python

I am trying to mock a class with the following code snippet:

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock

class TestMocking(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_mock_method_returns(self):
       my_mock = Mock()
       my_mock.my_method.return_value = "hello"
       self.assertEquals("hello",my_mock.my_method())


if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

While running the code, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named mock
```

I have installed mock with the following command:
    pip install mock

And I have the following output:

```
Collecting mock
  Downloading mock-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
  100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.4MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in 
  /home/sajjad/Dokument/InstalledProgram/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from mock)
  Collecting pbr>=0.11 (from mock)
  Downloading pbr-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98kB)
  100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 3.4MB/s 
  Installing collected packages: pbr, mock
  Successfully installed mock-2.0.0 pbr-2.0.0
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3, and on which OS?

Comment: I am trying to run the code snippet with python 2.7 at Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 3.5; mock is already [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) in that version, and you don't need to install it. You should import it like this:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
```